# Session management in angular4 Restful Webservice

Tags: java, angular, rest, session

I have my app consists of angular4 for frontEnd and Restful webservice that handle request. 
The scenario is when I make login request I add merchant object that comes from  response object to session and when i send another request with merchant object 
and compare it with the merchant on the session.
The problem is the merchant on the session return null in the case of angular and if I send the same request from Postman extension merchant return successfully

```
MerchantDataModel merchantDataModel = (MerchantDataModel) httpRequest.getSession()
            .getAttribute(GeneralConstants.MERCHANT_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE);
```

I want to know where is the problem?